# Why do both the if and elif statements perform in my python code?

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, if-statement, variables

I'm trying to open an XML file and parse through it, looking through its tags and finding the text within each specific tag. If the text within the tag matches a string, I want it remove a part of the string or substitute it with something else.

However, it looks like for some reason my "if-statements" are not working. I want it to do something only when the variable "action" equals 'remove' and do something else only when the variable "action" equals 'substitute". However, when "action" equals 'substitute', the if statement performs, along with what's in the elif statement too. Also, the if, elif, and else statements within the second if statement do not seem to work either. Even when end_int does not equal none, what's inside the if statement happens but does not go on to the elif and else statements when "start_int == None" and for the remaining cases.

The mfn_pn variable is a barcode inputted by the user, something similar to ATL-157-1815, DFW-184-8378., ATL-324-3243., DFW-432-2343.

The XML file has the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <filter>
        <regex>ATL|LAX|DFW</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>DFW.+\.$</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char>-1</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\-</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\s</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex> T&amp;R$</regex >
        <start_char></start_char>
        <end_char>-4</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
</metadata>
```

The Python code I'm using is:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

# filters.xml is the file that holds the things to be filtered
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("filters.xml")

# Get the data in the XML file 
root = tree.getroot()

# Loop through filters
for x in root.findall('filter'):

    # Find the text inside the regex tag
    regex = x.find('regex').text

    # Find the text inside the start_char tag
    start_prim = x.find('start_char')
    
    # If the element exists assign its text to start variable
    start = start_prim.text if start_prim is not None else None
    start_int = int(start) if start is not None else None

    # Find the text inside the end_char tag
    end_prim = x.find('end_char')

    # If the element exists assign its text end variable
    end = end_prim.text if end_prim is not None else None
    end_int = int(end) if end is not None else None

    # Find the text inside the action tag
    action = x.find('action').text

    if action == 'remove':
        if re.match(r'%s' % regex, mfn_pn, re.IGNORECASE):
            if end_int == None:
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:]
            elif start_int == None:
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[:end_int]
            else: 
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:end_int]
                
    elif action == 'substitute':
        mfn_pn = re.sub(r'%s' % regex, '', mfn_pn)
```

Output:

If mfn_pn = 1PDFW 356-5789, I get FW3565789. It deletes the first 3 characters, even though it should look at the xml file and when regex equals 1P, only delete the first two characters because start_char is equal to 2. So mfn_pn = regex[start_int:] which should be mfn_pn = regex[2:], but for some reason it still thinks start_int is 3.

If mfn_pn = DFW 356-5789, I get 3565789. It is deleting the first three characters, even though regex does not match to any of the characters that should be deleted - it performs the if statement even though it should skip down to the elif statement.

It seems to be only getting what’s in the first “filter” tag and setting regex equal to only what’s in the first regex tag, start_int equal to what’s in only the first start_int, and end_char equal to what’s in only the first end_int. Within the if-statement, it doesn’t set regex equal to what’s in the remaining filter tags.

Comment: Try to reduce this to a [mre]. Have you tried adding `print` statement to various places in the code to get it to reveal to you what exactly the relevant variables contain?

Comment: 'mfn_pn' object has not been assigned in the code

Comment: Yes, I put print statements to test it out. Both the if and elif statements perform, even though I would think it would be one or the other. Also, for the if, elif, and else, only what’s in the if statement happens. It’s like it thinks end_int = is always None, even when it isn’t.

Comment: Update yur question so the code is. [mre] - INCLUDING setting up mfn_pn, doing all the prints you mention which show the path taken, i.e. add `print(f”remove {action=}”)` inside the if for remove, and `print(f”substitute {action=}”)` inside the elif for substitute, and adding a print of mfn_pn at the end of each if/elif, and a print of mfn_pn at the end.

Comment: What you’ve got to do is look at anything you’ve assumed, like  (say) ‘oh of course the re.match matches’ and prove/misprove those assumptions - e.g. In the inner if statement, print the values being tested and the results, so you can confirm your assumptions. It’s called debugging.

Comment: @barny I tried this and I'm not ever getting a value from inside the elif and else statements, so it thinks end_int always equals "None" and doesn't get when end_int is not "None". I also put print statements after "end_int = int(end) if end is not None else None" and here when it prints, it prints all the different values of end_int (end_char from the xml file). I'm not sure why it doesn't get them within the if, elif, and else statements.

Answer (score 0):

based on the output you want from 1PDFW 356-5789 and it will produce 3565789.If it is possible to change the regex I have suggestions as below for filters.xml and the python code

The XML file has the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <filter>
        <regex>ATL|LAX|DFW</regex >
        <start_char>2</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>DFW</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\-</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\s</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex> T&amp;R$</regex >
        <start_char></start_char>
        <end_char>-4</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
</metadata>
```

The Python code I'm using is:

```
import re
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

# filters.xml is the file that holds the things to be filtered
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("filter.xml")

# Get the data in the XML file
root = tree.getroot()

# Loop through filters
for x in root.findall('filter'):

    # Find the text inside the regex tag
    regex = x.find('regex').text

    # Find the text inside the start_char tag
    start_prim = x.find('start_char')

    # If the element exists assign its text to start variable
    start = start_prim.text if start_prim is not None else None
    start_int = int(start) if start is not None else None

    # Find the text inside the end_char tag
    end_prim = x.find('end_char')

    # If the element exists assign its text end variable
    end = end_prim.text if end_prim is not None else None
    end_int = int(end) if end is not None else None

    # Find the text inside the action tag
    action = x.find('action').text
    if action == 'remove':
        if re.search(r'%s\b' % regex,mfn_pn):
            mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:end_int]

    elif action == 'substitute':
        mfn_pn = re.sub(r'%s' % regex, '', mfn_pn)
```

Comment: I declared mfn_pn in a different part of my code. It is a user input as mentioned in the question above. I didn’t include it here to keep the question minimal. I want what’s in the re.max part of the code to make the changes to the mfn_pn. I know that it works because I used print statements to check, it’s just that it doesn’t loop through the entire if/elif statements.

Comment: Sophia, do not exaggerate the "minimal". Aim for a [mre] instead. You see which problems otherwise occur.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a minimal reproducible example without leaving things out and not getting my issue across.

Comment: maybe you can give an example of the output you want and how the current code is output

Comment: @Irvan Ariyanto I’ve updated my question to add the output at the end.